# Error when saving using active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake-task

I'm trying to save records using a `.rake` file. But I am getting an error when attempting to save changes.

error.message

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: versions.id: INSERT INTO "versions" ("app_id", "created_at", "icon_url", "id", "plist_url", "updated_at", "version_number") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

inbox.rake file

```
namespace :inbox do
  desc 'Check inbox for new app builds'
  task process_inbox: :environment do
    # initialize s3 client
    s3 = AWS::S3.new
    bucket = s3.buckets['my-bucket']
    s3_host = 'https://...s3.amazonaws.com/'

    exclude_inbox = bucket.objects.select do |s3_object|
      s3_object.key.exclude? '_inbox'
    end
    #find plist within the inbox
    plist_objects = exclude_inbox.select do |s3_object|
      s3_object.key.include? 'plist'
    end

    for plist_object in plist_objects
      plist = CFPropertyList::List.new(:data => plist_object.read)
      data = CFPropertyList.native_types(plist.value)

      name = data['items'][0]['metadata']['title']
      bundle_version = data['items'][0]['metadata']['bundle-version']
      plist_copy = plist_object.copy_to("#{name}/#{bundle_version}/#{name}.plist")
      kind = data['items'][0]['metadata']['kind']

      plist = CFPropertyList::List.new(:data => plist_copy.read)
      data = CFPropertyList.native_types(plist.value)
      icon_url = data['items'][0]['assets'][1]['url']
      full_url = plist_copy.url_for(:read)

      icon = bucket.objects[icon_url.gsub(s3_host, '')]

      #find app or create a new app based on its name and kind
      app = App.find_or_initialize_by(name: name, app_type: kind)
      #app.save unless app.id
      #find version or create new version base on app_id and bundle_version
      version = Version.find_or_initialize_by(app_id: app.id, id: bundle_version)
      version.plist_url =  full_url.scheme + '://' + full_url.host + full_url.path
      version.icon_url = icon.copy_to("#{name}/#{bundle_version}/#{icon_url.split('/').last.gsub('~','_')}").url_for(:read).to_s
      version.version_number = bundle_version
      version.app = app
      #update app version number
      app.version_number = version.version_number
      #save changes
      begin
        app.save
        version.save
        puts app.attributes , version.attributes
      rescue => error
        puts error.message
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: The error message says it all `UNIQUE constraint failed`. `versions.id` is required to be unique, and you're trying to insert a record with an id which already exists

Comment: @RocketR I understand that , but I don't know why. Now where in my code am i assigning the id manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problematic line:

```
version = Version.find_or_initialize_by(app_id: app.id, id: bundle_version)
```

This is more verbose but probably more what you want:

```
version = Version.find_by(id: bundle_version, app_id: app.id) || Version.new(app_id: app.id)
```

Comment: @Vimsha It was actually was because what I wanted but was `version = Version.find_or_initialize_by(version_number: bundle_version, app_id: app.id)`. Thanks to you both

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem

```
Version.find_or_initialize_by(app_id: app.id, id: bundle_version)
```

I am guessing id is primary key here. Since you are doing a `find_or_initialize` on two values, you will get a new version when there is a version in the database with given bundle_version but different app_id

You probably should be doing,

```
version = Version.find_or_initialize_by(id: bundle_version)
version.app_id = app.id
```

Comment: Eerie how similar our answers are! But I think you won the race by a hair. :-)